# Change data storing location in Neo4j in Ubuntu

Tags: neo4j

I have successfully installed neo4j with the port number 7474 and it works fine.

My problem is the data is stored into `/var/lib/neo4j`. This location in this directory is going to be full very soon. I want to change the data store location. How is this possible?

I have tried to edit the file `/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties` in the line

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use an absolute path for `org.neo4j.server.database.location` and make sure the directory is writable for the user running neo4j. 
An alternative is symlink your real `graph.db` folder to `/var/lib/neo4j`.