# failed importing a neo4j db, created on mac, in a ubuntu machine - is neo4j.conf on ubuntu different from mac?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, neo4j, configuration

I spent hours trying to figure out why setting absolute path to:

```
dbms.active_database = my_db/data/graph.db
```

in `neo4j.conf` file

- it was resulting in an empty db.

It turns out that the db I created on laptop, on *mac*, does not have a file named "`graph.db`". In fact, I cannot locate which is the db file: see folder structure below.

The configuration file on mac does not have any "`dbms.active_database`" variable nor "`dbms.directories.data`" which I see on ubuntu.

The structure of the db I populated on mac misses a file "graph.db".

This is my_db folder structure:

```
certificates
data
index
logs
neostore
neostore.counts.db.a
neostore.counts.db.b
neostore.id
neostore.labeltokenstore.db
neostore.labeltokenstore.db.id
neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names
neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names.id
neostore.nodestore.db
neostore.nodestore.db.id
neostore.nodestore.db.labels
neostore.nodestore.db.labels.id
neostore.propertystore.db
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.id
neostore.propertystore.db.id
neostore.propertystore.db.index
neostore.propertystore.db.index.id
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.id
neostore.propertystore.db.strings
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.id
neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db
neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.id
neostore.relationshipstore.db
neostore.relationshipstore.db.id
neostore.relationshiptypestore.db
neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.id
neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names
neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names.id
neostore.schemastore.db
neostore.schemastore.db.id
neostore.transaction.db.0
neostore.transaction.db.1
neostore.transaction.db.2
neostore.transaction.db.3
neostore.transaction.db.4
neostore.transaction.db.5
neostore.transaction.db.6
neostore.transaction.db.7
neostore.transaction.db.8
neostore.transaction.db.9
schema
store_lock
```

I want to copy it on a ubuntu machine, in a custom folder.
Could you explain the differences on mac and ubuntu, to make it compatible?
Should I create my db again on the new machine?

Answer (score 1):

graph.db is a folder.

As per your file list, your my_db is equivalent to graph_db.
Try to rename it.

Comment: For simplicity I renamed my_db as graph.db :
No success: `dbms.active_database=graph.db` and `dbms.directories.data=/var/www/example/` 
`/var/www/example/graph.db` owned by `neo4j:adm`, `curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1` shows db is not found. -  No error in /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log

Comment: Found that `dbms.directories.data=/var/www/example/` will create a `databases` subfolder in the variable path, and create an empty graph.db in it if missing. Tried to replaced with my db, still `curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1` shows no entity found.. - No error in `/var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log`

Comment: /var/www is for the apache webserver.
As you are transferring from mac to ubuntu,you should have a folder with a path alike this one on ubuntu
ow in the browser
/home/YOU/neo4j-community-3.1.0/data/databases/graph.db

Comment everything in your conf. If your content does not show in the browser, then create a few random nodes then go to see what are the latest created/modified files on your disk

Comment: also do not use node ids. just use the browser, do a query and see

Answer (score 0):

I found that neo4j write the database by default in:

`/usr/share/neo4j`

and not in:

`/var/lib/neo4j/`

as it is suggested in `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` from the lines commented out and suggested also in this answer:
[Change data storing location in Neo4j in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202024/change-data-storing-location-in-neo4j-in-ubuntu)

setting `dmbs.directories.data`  to `/usr/share/neo4j/data` in  `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` worked for me.

I am using neo4j 3.1.1 on debian, ubuntu 16.04.